# how to write content the parent which encloses the script tag

Tags: javascript

I am writing a script inside a  tag.

```
<ul class="boxes_tree">
  <li><strong>data</strong></li>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var itemStr ='[data1,data2]';
    itemStr=$.parseJSON(itemStr);
    if(itemStr){
          for (var key in itemStr)
          {
             if (itemStr.hasOwnProperty(key))
             {
                itemStr[key];
             }
          }
    }
  </script>
</ul>
```

now inplace of  `itemStr[key];` I want to add a `li` tag with `itemStr[key]` as content of `li` tag.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I tried document.write(itemStr[key]); but that will write the content to the document but not inside the parent tag

Comment: So create the li element, you've heard of document.createElement() right?

Comment: but that will create the element at the document level right?

Comment: how do I refer the enclosing ul tag from inside the script tag without using any ID

Comment: What the data1, data2 is? Also, you enumerating properties of `itemStr` Array instance, not elements in array

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.write`:

```
document.write("<li>" + itemStr[key] + "</li>");
```

As far as I know, that is the only way to achieve what you are trying to do. However, you might want to reconsider your design altogether. because using document.write is considered a [poor practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice).

Comment: this doesn't help.. because this erase whole of my page contents and writes the li tags

Comment: No it does not - as long as you do not call it as a function after load

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with valid JSON

You use jQuery anyway so [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/BwzkM/)

```
$(function() {
  var itemStr ='[{"var":"data1"},{"var":"data2"}]';
  itemStr=$.parseJSON(itemStr);
  var $ul = $("#tree");
  if(itemStr){
    $(itemStr).each(function(i, val) {
      $ul.append("<li>"+val.var+"</li>");
    });
  }
});
```

---

document.write version: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/UzRj4/)

Answer (score 0):

How about move it to the head and make it this way with jQuery?

```
$('.boxes_tree').append("<li>" + itemStr[key] + "</li>");
```